# Inplace modification of incron monitored files

Tags: samba, rsync, pipe, libav, inotify

I have samba share where users create video files, i need to stripe audio tracks from that video files and rsync new files to remote folder.
I monitor the samba share with CLOSE_WRITE option, to strip audio I use avconv.
And here is the problem, I need to create new files with avconv, but that means that another WRITE_CLOSE will be triggered, an that is an endless loop, avconv can not write in the same file to help limit the iterations somehow.
Is there a way to do that without creating files in another folder? Pipes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the conversion output to another directory, and move back when done. This will only trigger MOVED_TO, since the actual writes will have already happened elsewhere.

Comment: thanks this is a useful advice, there are some other keys like IN_MODIFY that might help.